Web form automation with python
I need to create an automation to fill out the registration form in this link:
Im testing filling out the agency name but i keep getting an error stating "input-53" doesnt exist. Once i figure how to overcome this i can move to other fields.
Doe anyone know where this error comes from? or what is the correct html source i should use?
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import json
import time

# Define the JSON data
json_data = {
    "EventID": "10204699324324573",
    "Requested_time": "17:54:42.864000+00:00",
    "agency": {
        "FEIN": "26-4430090",
        "NPN": "13468670",
        "address": {
            "city": "SAN ANTONIO",
            "state": "TX",
            "street": "2042  OAK PKY 105",
            "zip_code": "78289"
        },
        "contact_info": [
            {"email": "ag@example.com", "phone_number": "2100086000", "source": "Agency"},
            {"email": "", "phone_number": "210-008-6000", "source": "NIPR"}
        ],
        "email": "ag@example.com",
        "agency_name": "EXAMPLE AGENCY, LLC"
    },
    "agent": {
        "NPN": "3800006",
        "email": "admin@example.com",
        "first_name": "Jhon",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "phone_number": "2108966000",
        "title_position": "Owner",
        "validated": True
    },
    "carrier": "Carrier",
    "request": {
        "questions": {"accept_terms": "true", "why_appointment": None},
        "status": "APPROVED"
    },
    "requested_at": "T17:54:42.616754562Z"
}

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

try:
    # Navigate to the target website
    driver.get("link")

    # Fill out the form fields (replace these selectors with the actual ones)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-53").send_keys(json_data["agency"]["agency_name"])





finally:
    # Pause to allow inspection of the filled form
    time.sleep(10)
    # Clean up and close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()


this is the html sourceL


Changes made to the code:

As others have said, you need to switch into the IFRAME first before performing action on the targeted element

For some reason ID locator strategy is not working. I used XPath as below and it works
 By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Agency Name']//following::input[1]


Used selenium's waits to locate elements effectively

Open URL in full screen, although this may not make difference, I prefer to run browser in full screen unless there is specific requirement not to do so.
 driver.maximize_window()



Check the complete working code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import json
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Define the JSON data
json_data = {
    "EventID": "10204699324324573",
    "Requested_time": "17:54:42.864000+00:00",
    "agency": {
        "FEIN": "26-4430090",
        "NPN": "13468670",
        "address": {
            "city": "SAN ANTONIO",
            "state": "TX",
            "street": "2042  OAK PKY 105",
            "zip_code": "78289"
        },
        "contact_info": [
            {"email": "ag@agentero.com", "phone_number": "2100086000", "source": "Agency"},
            {"email": "", "phone_number": "210-008-6000", "source": "NIPR"}
        ],
        "email": "ag@agentero.com",
        "agency_name": "AGENTERO AGENCY, LLC"
    },
    "agent": {
        "NPN": "3800006",
        "email": "admin@agentero.com",
        "first_name": "Jhon",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "phone_number": "2108966000",
        "title_position": "Owner",
        "validated": True
    },
    "carrier": "Coterie",
    "request": {
        "questions": {"accept_terms": "true", "why_appointment": None},
        "status": "APPROVED"
    },
    "requested_at": "T17:54:42.616754562Z"
}

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    # Navigate to the target website
    driver.get("https://coterieinsurance.com/agentero/")
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//iframe)[1]")))
    # Fill out the form fields (replace these selectors with the actual ones)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Agency Name']//following::input[1]"))).send_keys(json_data["agency"]["agency_name"])


finally:
    # Pause to allow inspection of the filled form
    time.sleep(10)
    # Clean up and close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()


the input is in a iframe, not the root html.
add this code before driver.find_element
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

